# How to get value of textfield in alertdialog with custom layout

Tags: android

This is my layout for the dialog :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I call the dialog from a class extending `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Here is my class extending `DialogFragment`:-

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_settings, null));



        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                try {
                    //The problem starts
                    //How do I get the reference to the EditText 

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I call the `MyDialogFragment` from my class as follows:-

```
      MyDialogFragment dial = new MyDialogFragment();
      dial.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"tag");
```

Now, How do I get the text in the `EditText` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `dialog` for getting text from EditText which is in AlertDialog:

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                try { 
                     EditText editdate = (EditText) ((Dialog)   
                                            dialog).findViewById(R.id.date);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

or you can also do it using inflated view :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_settings, null);
builder.setView(view);
....
EditText editdate = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
```

Comment: I thought so. But did not cast `dialog` to `AlertDialog` Thanks

Comment: @BenLind: i have also added another option please and it is `Dialog` instead of `AlertDialog`

Comment: Awesome..the second method is the best. With that I can initialize `EditText` before the `onClick` method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to give id of EditText

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Do some changes in code like following:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_settings, null);
            builder.setView(v);

            EditText txtDate = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            txtDate.setText("Ben Lind");

            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    try {
                        //The problem starts
                        //How do I get the reference to the EditText 

                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return builder.create();
        }
    }
```